# Moving menu using placement.info

Tags: orchardcms

Is it possible to move the Menu shape into the Header zone using a Place element in the placement.info?

I tried the following but it had no effect:

```
<Place Menu="Header:after"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Placement is for moving the shapes for content parts between the local zones where the content item they belong to is rendered. So it is meaningless for menu, as this is not a part. The menu is being rendered into a top-level zone called Navigation, which is usually defined in layout. So what you need to do is override or alternate the template for layout in your theme and move the navigation zone.